# How to return the host name of the video from a URL using regex in php?

Tags: php, facebook, youtube

There  are two urls:

> 1- http://www.facebook.com/?v=107084586333124'
>
> 2- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws_RjMYE85o

As you can see, both links contains the ?v=..............

Im using a function to retrieve the video ID and the name of the host (youtube, facebook, etc).

Im using this function to get both id and host name

```
function get_video_id($url){
    $video_id = "";
    //YOUTUBE
    if(preg_match('#(?<=(?:v|i)=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=(?:v|i)\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=embed\/)[^"&\n]+|(?<=(?:v|i)=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&\n]+#', $url, $videoid)){
            if(strlen($videoid[0])) { 
                $video_id = 'youtube:_:'.$videoid[0]; 
            }
    }

    //VIMEO
    if(preg_match('#(https?://)?(www.)?(player.)?vimeo.com/([a-z]*/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*#', $url, $videoid)){
            if(strlen($videoid[5])) { 
                $video_id = 'vimeo:_:'.$videoid[5]; 
            }
    }

    // Facebook 
    if(preg_match("~/videos/(?:t\.\d+/)?(\d+)~i", $url, $videoid)){
        if(strlen($videoid[0])) { 
            $video_id = 'facebook:_:'.$videoid[1]; 
        }
    }

    return $video_id;


}
    $exp = explode(':_:',get_video_id($_POST['video_url']));
    echo $exp[0] .'=>'.$exp[1];
```

**$exp[0]** should return the host name (youtube, vimeo, facebook ....etc);

and **$exp[1]** return the video id.

The function is working fine but the problem I encounter is that when I submit a facebook video link which contains the **?v=**

> **(eg. http://www.facebook.com/?v=107084586333124')**

it always returns **youtube** as a host name. unlike when I submit a link like this one:

> **https://www.facebook.com/LadBlab/videos/540736926073557/**

it return **facebook** and thus working fine.

How to check if the url is a facebook video or not when a user submit a link like this one and not confuse it with youtube?

> **http://www.facebook.com/?v=107084586333124'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
$url = 'http://facebook.com/?v=4654654';
if(strpos($url, 'facebook') != FALSE) {
  //facebook link
} else if(strpos($url, 'youtube') != FALSE) {
  //youtubelink
} else {
  //someother link
}
```

And then apply your preg_match to each link separately to get the video id.